# How to convert MTLTexture to CVMetalTextureRef or CMSampleBufferRef in Metal?

Tags: metal

I have encountered a problem in converting MTLTexture to CVMetalTextureRef or CVPixelBufferRef , my code is this :

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(_screenPixelBuffer, 0);//必须锁定内存

    id <MTLTexture> outputTexture = drawable.texture;

    MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, drawable.layer.drawableSize.width, drawable.layer.drawableSize.height);

    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    int bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * drawable.layer.drawableSize.width;

    NSLog(@"drawable.layer.drawableSize.width = %f, drawable.layer.drawableSize.height = %f", drawable.layer.drawableSize.width, drawable.layer.drawableSize.height);
    NSLog(@"textureType = %lu, width = %lu, height = %lu, depth = %lu, arrayLength = %lu， mipmapLevelCount = %lu, sampleCount = %lu", outputTexture.textureType, outputTexture.width, outputTexture.height, outputTexture.depth, outputTexture.arrayLength, outputTexture.mipmapLevelCount, outputTexture.sampleCount);

    void *tmpBuffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(_screenPixelBuffer);

    [outputTexture getBytes:tmpBuffer bytesPerRow:bytesPerRow fromRegion:region mipmapLevel:0];


    [_iv setImage:[self imageFromPixelBuffer:_screenPixelBuffer]];

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_screenPixelBuffer, 0);//解锁内存
```

But the image the UIImageview displays is not right. [The complete code here](https://github.com/oklyc/MetalCameraSample-master-2).

Comment: Could you please specify what behaviour you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @haawa I want get the graphic what the Metal API rendered. In other words, I want record the screen.

Comment: Refer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842661/how-to-convert-a-mtltexture-to-cvpixelbuffer-to-write-into-an-avassetwriter

Comment: Did you figured out to make it?