# How to convert a MTLTexture to CVpixelBuffer to write into an AVAssetWriter?

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

I have a requirement to apply filters on the live video and I'm trying to do it in Metal.

But I have encountered problem with converting the MTLTexture into CVPixelBuffer after encoding the filter into destination filter. Reference (https://github.com/oklyc/MetalCameraSample-master-2)

Here are my codes.

```
if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer {
                CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.init(rawValue: 0))             
                let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, Int(currentDrawable.layer.drawableSize.width), Int(currentDrawable.layer.drawableSize.height))                    
                let bytesPerPixel = 4;
                let bytesPerRow = CGFloat(bytesPerPixel) * currentDrawable.layer.drawableSize.width

                let tempBuffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
                destinationTexture.getBytes(tempBuffer!, bytesPerRow: Int(bytesPerRow), from: region1, mipmapLevel: 0)

                let image = self.imageFromCVPixelBuffer(buffer: pixelBuffer)
                CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.init(rawValue: 0))

            }
```

The method imageFromCVPixelBuffer looks like this.

```
func imageFromCVPixelBuffer(buffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> UIImage {

    let ciimage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let cgimgage = context.createCGImage(ciimage, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(buffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer)))

    let uiimage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimgage!)

    return uiimage
}
```

Here is the screen shot of the image rendering through metal

[image]

Here is the screen shot of the same image converting MTLTexture to CVPixelBuffer.

[image]

Converting MTLtexture into CVPixelBuffer is required to write into an AVAssetWriter and then saving it to the Library.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I am also trying to use mtltexture with avassetwriter. Can you share your final code please.

Comment: Converting to UIImage I believe is pretty slow and will give you poor performance if you are making a video.  Obviously that's totally fine for a screenshot however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't compute `bytesPerRow` yourself like that. It's being passed in to Metal to let Metal know how to arrange the rows. You want Metal to arrange them the way `CVPixelBuffer` expects them. Therefore, you should use `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow()` to determine the value.

Comment: I believe rows in a CVPixelBuffer are 32-pixel aligned.  This leads to issues if you start making assumptions about these buffers not containing any padding bytes at the end of each row.

Comment: Wait, but where are you copying pixels data from mtltexture to cvpixelbuffer?