# Save depth images from TrueDepth camera

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x, truedepth-camera

I am trying to save depth images from the iPhoneX TrueDepth camera. Using the [AVCamPhotoFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamPhotoFilter/Listings/README_md.html) sample code, I am able to view the depth, converted to grayscale format, on the screen of the phone in real-time. I cannot figure out how to save the sequence of depth images in the raw (16 bits or more) format.

I have `depthData` which is an instance of `AVDepthData`. One of its members is `depthDataMap` which is an instance of `CVPixelBuffer` and image format type `kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat16`. Is there a way to save it to the phone to transfer for offline manipulation?

Comment: Do you want to save a sequence of "still" depth images or write video? Note that the sample code project you're citing already includes tools for converting depth buffers to grayscale textures, so you can look at existing questions regarding [getting `CVPixelBuffer`s out of Metal textures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44842661/957768) or [recording video from a Metal renderer with AVAssetWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43838089/957768).

Comment: @rickster, I want to save a sequence of still depth images. I don't want to convert depth images to grayscale textures, but save the raw depth values (that are in meters).

Comment: @rickster, for me grayscale is good solution (the parser can decode the depth information) but I can't find a way to save 16bits grayscale video. The examples I have uses regular rgba video with same value in all channels but then you have 8bits for depth and not 16.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no standard video format for "raw" depth/disparity maps, which might have something to do with AVCapture not really offering a way to record it.

You have a couple of options worth investigating here:

1. Convert depth maps to grayscale textures (which you can do using the code in the [AVCamPhotoFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamPhotoFilter/Listings/README_md.html) sample code), then pass those textures to `AVAssetWriter` to produce a grayscale video. Depending on the video format and grayscale conversion method you choose, other software you write for reading the video might be able to recover depth/disparity info with sufficient precision for your purposes from the grayscale frames.
2. Anytime you have a `CVPixelBuffer`, you can get at the data yourself and do whatever you want with it. Use [`CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1457128-cvpixelbufferlockbaseaddress) (with the [`readOnly`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvpixelbufferlockflags/1457186-readonly) flag) to make sure the content won't change while you read it, then copy data from the pointer [`CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1457115-cvpixelbuffergetbaseaddress) provides to wherever you want. (Use other pixel buffer functions to see how many bytes to copy, and unlock the buffer when you're done.)

   Watch out, though: if you spend too much time copying from buffers, or otherwise retain them, they won't get deallocated as new buffers come in from the capture system, and your capture session will hang. (All told, it's unclear without testing whether a device has the memory & I/O bandwidth for much recording this way.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Compression library to create a zip file with the raw CVPixelBuffer data. 
Few problems with this solution.

1. It's a lot of data and zip is not a good compression. (the compressed file is 20 times bigger than 32bits per frame video with the same number of frames).
2. Apple's Compression library creates a file which standard zip program does't open. I use zlib in C code to read it and use `inflateInit2(&strm, -15);` to make it work.
3. You'll need to do some work to export the file out of your application

Here is my code (which I limited to 250 frames since it hold it in RAM but you can flush to disk if needed more frames):

```
//  DepthCapture.swift
//  AVCamPhotoFilter
//
//  Created by Eyal Fink on 07/04/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Resonai. All rights reserved.
//
// Capture the depth pixelBuffer into a compress file.
// This is very hacky and there are lots of TODOs but instead we need to replace
// it with a much better compression (video compression)....

import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import Compression


class DepthCapture {
    let kErrorDomain = "DepthCapture"
    let maxNumberOfFrame = 250
    lazy var bufferSize = 640 * 480 * 2 * maxNumberOfFrame  // maxNumberOfFrame frames
    var dstBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?
    var frameCount: Int64 = 0
    var outputURL: URL?
    var compresserPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<compression_stream>?
    var file: FileHandle?

    // All operations handling the compresser oobjects are done on the
    // porcessingQ so they will happen sequentially
    var processingQ = DispatchQueue(label: "compression",
                                    qos: .userInteractive)


    func reset() {
        frameCount = 0
        outputURL = nil
        if self.compresserPtr != nil {
            //free(compresserPtr!.pointee.dst_ptr)
            compression_stream_destroy(self.compresserPtr!)
            self.compresserPtr = nil
        }
        if self.file != nil {
            self.file!.closeFile()
            self.file = nil
        }
    }
    func prepareForRecording() {
        reset()
        // Create the output zip file, remove old one if exists
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
        self.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("Depth"))
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: self.outputURL!.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        self.file = FileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath: self.outputURL!.path)
        if self.file == nil {
            NSLog("Cannot create file at: \(self.outputURL!.path)")
            return
        }

        // Init the compression object
        compresserPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<compression_stream>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        compression_stream_init(compresserPtr!, COMPRESSION_STREAM_ENCODE, COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
        dstBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
        compresserPtr!.pointee.dst_ptr = dstBuffer!
        //defer { free(bufferPtr) }
        compresserPtr!.pointee.dst_size = bufferSize


    }
    func flush() {
        //let data = Data(bytesNoCopy: compresserPtr!.pointee.dst_ptr, count: bufferSize, deallocator: .none)
        let nBytes = bufferSize - compresserPtr!.pointee.dst_size
        print("Writing \(nBytes)")
        let data = Data(bytesNoCopy: dstBuffer!, count: nBytes, deallocator: .none)
        self.file?.write(data)
    }

    func startRecording() throws {
        processingQ.async {
            self.prepareForRecording()
        }
    }
    func addPixelBuffers(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        processingQ.async {
            if self.frameCount >= self.maxNumberOfFrame {
                // TODO now!! flush when needed!!!
                print("MAXED OUT")
                return
            }

            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
            let add : UnsafeMutableRawPointer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)!
            self.compresserPtr!.pointee.src_ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(add.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))
            let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
            self.compresserPtr!.pointee.src_size = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer) * height
            let flags = Int32(0)
            let compression_status = compression_stream_process(self.compresserPtr!, flags)
            if compression_status != COMPRESSION_STATUS_OK {
                NSLog("Buffer compression retured: \(compression_status)")
                return
            }
            if self.compresserPtr!.pointee.src_size != 0 {
                NSLog("Compression lib didn't eat all data: \(compression_status)")
                return
            }
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
            // TODO(eyal): flush when needed!!!
            self.frameCount += 1
            print("handled \(self.frameCount) buffers")
        }
    }
    func finishRecording(success: @escaping ((URL) -> Void)) throws {
        processingQ.async {
            let flags = Int32(COMPRESSION_STREAM_FINALIZE.rawValue)
            self.compresserPtr!.pointee.src_size = 0
            //compresserPtr!.pointee.src_ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(0)
            let compression_status = compression_stream_process(self.compresserPtr!, flags)
            if compression_status != COMPRESSION_STATUS_END {
                NSLog("ERROR: Finish failed. compression retured: \(compression_status)")
                return
            }
            self.flush()
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                success(self.outputURL!)
            }
            self.reset()
        }
    }
}
```