# Is there a way to encode Apple Metal rendered graphics into a video file?

Tags: 3d, shader, render, metal, metalkit

I would like to render 3D graphics generated by Metal (Apple shading language) into a video file at specified resolution and FPS, without showing it on the screen. The render can happen at slower than real time, so I should be allowed to compute each frame longer than it would be for real time display. If this is possible, how can I do it? I’m currently using MTKView to render into a screen.

Comment: Use `AVAssetWriter` to write a video, convert Metal textures to `CVPixelBuffer`, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842661/how-to-convert-a-mtltexture-to-cvpixelbuffer-to-write-into-an-avassetwriter

Comment: @Itai thanks! Could have posted that as an answer :)